# Filtering data based on equal rows for certain columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
raw_data = {
                'age': [20, 20, 20, 22, 21],
                'favorite_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'blue','yellow', "green"],
                'grade': [92,"" , 92, 95, 70],
           'key': ['a', 'b', 'Total', 'a', 'b']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df

age favorite_color  grade   key
20   blue            92      a
20   blue                    b
20   blue            92    Total
22   yellow          95      a
21   green           70      b
```

For equal values of "age" and "favorite_color"
if "grade" for "total" value of "key" = sum of "grade" for non total value of "key",
replace grade to 0 for "Total".

So my output dataframe should look like the below:

```
age favorite_color  grade   key
20   blue            92      a
20   blue                    b
20   blue            0     Total
22   yellow          95      a
21   green           70      b
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide the code that you have tried so far? The purpose of SO is preliminary to debug your code and point you to the right direction, rather someone simply coding for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my solution:

First convert non-blank grades to ints:

```
df.grade = df.grade.astype(int, errors='ignore')
```

Make a function to check non-total Sum = Total sum

```
def fixer(x):
    if x[x.key == 'Total']['grade'].sum() == x[x.key == 'Total']['grade'].sum():
        x.loc[x.key == 'Total', 'grade'] = 0
    return x
```

Profit!

```
df[df.grade.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int))].groupby(
    ['age', 'favorite_color']).apply(fixer)


    age     favorite_color  grade   key
0   20         blue         92      a
2   20         blue         0     Total
3   22         yellow       95      a
4   21        green         70      b
```

Comment: The above solution changes all the values of column "grade" to 0 if "key" = "Total", even if the rows on "age " and "favorite_color"  columns are different. For example if the dataframe looks like below:

Comment: Its not getting applicable to the below dataframe  
raw_data = {'age': [20, 20, 20, 22, 21],
                'favorite_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'blue','yellow', "green"],
                'grade': [92,np.nan , 92, 95, 70],
           'key': ['a', 'b', 'Total', 'Total', 'b']}